# Transformation movement by using Accelerometer data

Tags: transformation, accelerometer, gyroscope

Is It possible to make transformation movement by using Accelerometer data or Accel + Gyro ?
as we know, we can make rotation by using Accel or Gyro data.
However, how can we make transformation movement?
I know this is still problematic and experimental. but there must be some ways to reach.

Is there any algorithm or math formula solving this problem?

Comment: Do you mean translational movement? Rotation and scale are also transformation.

Answer (score 1):

The accelerometer is very imprecise, in fact all of them are. That's the main reason you need to combine 3 or more sensors to get something that even remotely resembles the actual rotation.

The other big problem with the accelerometer is that it's in m/s², that means to get a position from this you'll need to first multiply it with the time difference to get the velocity, add that to the total velocity, then once again to get the position that you add to the total position. This means that even a small drift will mean multiple meters in a second.

For example, if the accelerometer outputs 0.1m/s² more, then it should and with 60fps you'll get a drift of around 3 meters in the position at the end.

If you need to measure large distances, then stick to the GPS instead.